# Citation Problems when using subfiles

Tags: bibliographies, citing, subfiles

I am aiming for a multifile Latex document and I am working on it in Overleaf. I would like each chapter to have separate bibliography sections (this can be done apparently with the `chapterbib` package). However, I cannot get my document to compile successfully; I am leaving a "minimal" project where the problem has been recreated:

Project Structure:

**[Chapters]** (Directory)

- **Chapter One** (contains Chapter One.bib and Chapter One.tex)

main.tex

[image]

**Chapter One.bib**

```
@article{PhysRev.97.1387,
  title = {Behavior of Neutral Particles under Charge Conjugation},
  author = {Gell-Mann, M. and Pais, A.},
  journal = {Phys. Rev.},
  volume = {97},
  issue = {5},
  pages = {1387--1389},
  numpages = {0},
  year = {1955},
  month = {Mar},
  publisher = {American Physical Society},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRev.97.1387},
  url = {https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRev.97.1387}
}
```

**Chapter One.tex**

```
This is Chapter I, \cite{PhysRev.97.1387}.
\bibliography{Chapters/Chapter One/Chapter 1}
```

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{cite}

\title{Example}
\author{Author}
\date{February 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{Chapter I}
\subfile{Chapters/Chapter One/Chapter 1.tex}
\end{document}
```

However, the project above compiles with non-fatal errors but does not show the citations. I doubt that I have made a mistake in the naming of the citation since it is automatically suggested by Overleaf. The corresponding warning message is:

```
Citation `PhysRev.97.1387' on page 3 undefined on input line 1.
```

which sounds weird since I have defined it and connected it with the right bib file. I am also leaving a link for the project:
https://www.overleaf.com/5781314855tszqjcvfsrmk

Comment: Does you document contain a `\bibliographystyle` directive?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I just added a \bibliographystyle{abbrv} line on my Chapter 1.tex file and it changes nothing.

Comment: After adding the `\bibiiographystyle` instruction, did you run a full recompile cycle (LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more)? A separate question: Did you make the `\bibiiographystyle` instruction apply just to Chapter 1? Which bibliography style should be employed in the other chapters?

Comment: This might be part of the problem, but I am a bit blind to what Overleaf does exactly when I am hitting compile. Usually, when compiling manually (outside of Overleaf) you do what you said. I will try give it a try in a local terminal.

Comment: Probably Overleaf hides the errors messages. The main problem seems to be that you load the chapter with `\subfile`, but add the full path in the `\bibliography` command. In files loaded by `\subfile`, choose paths relative to the subfile, not to the main file. At least under Linux, there is a second issue: the spaces in the path to the subfile cause problems when calling bibtex. If you plan to leave the subfiles they are now (without `\documentclass` of their own), don't use `subfiles`, but replace `\subfile` by `\input` (but then leave the path in `\bibliographystyle` as it was).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When loading a file `sub.tex` with `\subfile`, choose any path information in it relative to `sub.tex`. For commands other than `\input`, `\includegraphics` and `\bibliography`, you may have to wrap the relative path additionally into a `\subfix` command, like `\subfix{...relpath...}`.

An additional problem may be that spaces in directory and file names are not handled correctly when handing them to external programs like `bibtex`. It's safer to avoid them if you want to stay portable.

Here is a version of your code that compiles:

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{cite}
\title{Example}
\author{Author}
\date{February 2023}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{Chapter I}
\subfile{Chapters/ChapterOne/Chapter1.tex}
\end{document}

% Chapters/ChapterOne/Chapter1.tex
This is Chapter I, \cite{PhysRev.97.1387}.
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{Chapter1}

% Chapters/ChapterOne/Chapter1.bib
% See original posting
```

**Note on using the `subfiles` package:** In the original posting, `Chapter1.tex` does not contain a `\documentclass` command of its own. This may be due to providing a stripped down minimal example. However, if this is a feature of the original TeX code, then *don't use the `subfiles` package*. The whole point of this package is to reuse/skip preambles. Instead, replace `\subfile` by `\input`. If you like the feature of having paths relative to subfiles, then use the `import` package and replace `\subfile` by `\import`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: @Heath Please also check my note regarding the use of the `subfiles` package that I just added.